# VBA SaveAs saving as File type instead of .xlsm

Tags: vba, excel, save

When a user opens up this workbook, I want to force them to save the file as a new file immediately. The dialog box opens up but it will only let you save it as "All Files".

[image]

```
Dim Workbook_Orig As Variant

    Workbook_Orig = Application.GetSaveAsFilename

    If Workbook_Orig <> False Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
        Filename:="File Name", _
        FileFormat:=52
    End If
```

In place of the "52" I've tried "xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled" but that made no difference.

Can you not SaveAs immediately? Do you have to make a change to the file or something?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can always force it by `Filename:="File Name" & ".xlsm"` but odd that doesn't work.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked, I wasn't completing the saving of the file because I assumed it wouldn't save it under the right file type (since that's what it did when I didn't specify the file format) but even though it indicates "All Files" it does save it as a .xlsm file.

Comment: How do I let the user input the file name? I don't want to choose that for them.

Comment: `How do I let the user input the file name`.... `Workbook_Orig` Edit: while my force works, both answers below are better.

Answer (score 3):

Try specifying a *file filter*:

```
Workbook_Orig = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        fileFilter:="XLSM Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing the `FileFormat` only matters if they don't select anything in the dialogue box (since that is the only time workbook_orig = False)

Try specifying the *file filter* parameter

```
Workbook_Orig = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm),*.xlsm")
```

In your `GetSaveAsFileName` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Why not present the user with an InputBox?   Have them enter the new file name and have the macro perform the save as.

Something like:

```
Sub saveAs()
    userAnswer = InputBox("Please enter filename")
    ActiveWorkbook.saveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\" & userAnswer & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8, _
    Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

```
Sub saveAs()
    userAnswer = InputBox("Please enter filename")
    userDirectory = InputBox("Please enter directory to save file")
    ActiveWorkbook.saveAs Filename:= _
    userDirectory & "\" & userAnswer & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8, _
    Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: This works great! Any way to let them pick the path? I'm using this tool to generate sales quotes. The sales team obviously stores their quotes in different locations and I want them to be able to find where they save their quotes.

Comment: you can, but then you have to worry about error handling typos and things like.

Comment: i edited my original answer for users to include a save directory.  if you want to get fancy you can use a user form, but this would require more code than the above.  let me know : )