# Is there a way to use SaveCopyAs with the dialog, custom name and choosing the current file type (format) (52 or .xlsm)

Tags: excel, vba, filenames, file-copying, save-as

I need code that will save a copy of the active workbook with a custom name, specifying the file type (.xlsm).

I have used ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs with a custom name. This will save a copy but there isn't a dialog box for the user to change the name or location if they need to and I can't seem to get it to save with the correct file extension.

I have also used Application.GetSaveAsFileName with a custom name. This will bring up the dialog box so the user can change the location and name however it doesn't give the option to save it as .xlsm and it doesn't save a copy so the user has to reopen the original file.

Is there a way to get the dialog box with the custom name and have it save as .xlsm? I can't seem to find anything out there with this question.

Here is the code I have.

```
Private Sub cbsave_Click()

Dim fn As Variant
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim qn As String
Dim fe As String

qn = "Copy of " & Sheet11.Range("QN") & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
fe = "." & LCase(Right(wb1.Name, Len(wb1.Name) - InStrRev(wb1.Name, ".", , 1)))

fn = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Copy of " & Sheet11.Range("QN") & Format(Now, 
"dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss"), filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlmx")

'ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileName:="Copy of " & Sheet11.Range("QN") & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm- 
 ss" & "fe")

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your `FileFilter` is off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA SaveAs saving as File type instead of .xlsm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418708/vba-saveas-saving-as-file-type-instead-of-xlsm)

Comment: You can't use SaveCopyAs to change the file type.

Comment: ^^^ That too :)