# Save Workbook as .xlsm

Tags: excel, vba, file, save, save-as

I am trying to save my workbook via Macro.

Unfortunately with the following code it will be saved as a .txt file.

I also tried using FIlterIndex = 2 but it didn't work at all.

Does anyone have the solution for me?

Much appreciated!

```
Sub Save_Workbook_NewName()

Dim workbook_Name As Variant
workbook_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
If workbook_Name <> False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=workbook_Name, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
               
            
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: [Perhaps helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418708/vba-saveas-saving-as-file-type-instead-of-xlsm). Try `fileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm),*.xlsm"` with `GetSaveAsFilename`.

Comment: sorry, I am very unfamiliar with VBA,  should I replace or add your solution to my macro?

Comment: `workbook_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm),*.xlsm")`.